# Java app engine - how to emit XML from app.yaml to web.xml

Tags: google-app-engine, web.xml, app.yaml

In the Java documentation for app angine there is this section: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml#Java_app_yaml_Custom_XML_output

that says:

> If you need to use features of the Java web.xml which are not directly
>   supported in app.yaml, you can include a block of XML that will be
>   included directly into web.xml.

but the example given there seems to be unrelated.

does anyone know how to emit XML from app.yaml to web.xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your xml to the web_xml key, please see the example bellow:

```
web_xml: |
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
```

The above xml will be merged to the generated web.xml

Comment: thanks. 
I am going to check it out.
any references to where you got this from?

Comment: When I had the same problem, went google searching for "web_xml appengine example" and found a gist in github with an example. Google documentation doesn't shows an example. search for web_xml at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml